# Выходит ошибка когда собираю проект на maven

Tags: spring, maven, компиляция

Проект на Spring Framework

Я получаю ошибку когда запускаю mvn clean install -DskipTests:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project postcodeapp: Compilation failure
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Вот мои версии maven и java:

```
C:\Users\KazPost\Desktop\citypostkz\back-end>mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11- 
10T22:41:47+06:00)
Maven home: C:\maven\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre
Default locale: ru_RU, platform encoding: Cp1251
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"

C:\Users\KazPost\Desktop\citypostkz\back-end>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_131

C:\Users\KazPost\Desktop\citypostkz\back-end>java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

maven-compiler-plugin в pom.xml

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>testCompile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Здесь полный pom.xml и stackTrace: https://gist.github.com/Abdubek/741b4e543b2f376cb2bff42dba447a89

Когда я запускаю mvn clean install, создается папка target и выходит ошибка, потом когда я запускаю локально, выходит такая ошибка

```
Error: java: java.lang.AssertionError
Error: java: at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:126)
```

потом Если я удалю папку target и запущу локально еще раз запускается успешно. но если потом я запущу mvn clean install опять перестает запускатся локально и build.

Comment: попробуйте так `mvn clean install -DskipTests=true`

Comment: Я решил проблему, когда я интегрировался, wsdl-ка создала com\microsoft\schemas_2003_10\serialization\ObjectFactory.java вот такой файл, из за этого выходила ошибка

Comment: @AbdubekZholay то есть была какая-то проблема с другим плагином для кодогенерации и не корректно работающим с ним clean?

Comment: @VladMamaev, там генерировалась ObjectFactory.java отдельно как com\microsoft\schemas_2003_10\serialization\ObjectFactory.java и в файлах  wsdl-ки, компилятор ругалась за то что был 2 класса с одинаковым именем